# Acces Casa full node with Python

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, full-node

I have a bitcoin-core full node running and I want to access my node in Python, how can I retrieve the blockchain info?

Answer (score 1):

You can use RPC bitcoin framework for creating the request to the node to get information.

With python exist more library, I preferer this [python-bitcoinrpc](https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc) but a list the library is [here](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=bitcoin%20rpc&type=Repositories)

For configuring the node to accepting the request look this [reference](https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Bitcoind)

other util references

- [Complete bitcoin.conf file](https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc/blob/master/contrib/debian/examples/bitcoin.conf)
- [Gui generator bitcoin.conf](https://jlopp.github.io/bitcoin-core-config-generator/)
- [Api reference with other language](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC))
- [Official documantation command rpc](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/)

Comment: I try to establish a rpc connection with the AuthServiceProxy method from bitcoinrpc with the following parameters:  AuthServiceProxy ("http://casa-node.lan:mycasapassword@mycasaip:8332") but I get no acces.

Comment: Do you have an error in the stack-trace python? if you want an example for using the library, I wrote this simple script for creating a simple console GUI this is the [code](https://gist.github.com/vincenzopalazzo/1f1245ab200ed59a0604dee134f42863) if you have an error with my code, please public your bitcoin.conf and your bitcoin configuration